# Nutch Crawling Result as JSON

Tags: java, apache, web-crawler, nutch

I am using `apache-nutch-2.1` to crawl. Is it possible to get the crawled result as json? I wrote a java program to crawl using apache-nutch-2.1. How Would i retrive the crawled result as JSON. It may be a silly question but when i google it. There is no related to that.

How would add i get the crawled result s json?

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are looking for is already implemented: [Nutch-932 retrieve crawl results as JSON](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-932)

There are also examples how to use it in the link above.

Comment: I have crawled using /usr/local/nutch/framework/apache-nutch-1.4-bin/runtime/local/bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 10 -topN 1000 How would i achieve json

Comment: @jackyesind There's an example right on that page. It seems to require passing the results of the crawl to json_pp which will get you the JSON-formatted data you need.

Comment: @pallandt I am new to the nutch crawling i used the steps as mentioned here https://sites.google.com/site/profileswapnilkulkarni/tech-talk/nutchtutorialonubuntu10easysteps in this how would i add this example

Comment: I see, so you're on Ubuntu? Have you tried running the equivalent of [this example](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-932?focusedCommentId=12928355&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12928355)

Comment: Substitute with your own URLs of course. If you're on Debian/Unix you should already have curl instlled, if you want to double-check you can just run apt-get install curl

Comment: For json_pp, I see it is a Perl module on CPAN. Follow this short tutorial to install it [How to install perl modules through CPAN on ubuntu](http://egoleo.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/how-to-install-perl-modules-through-cpan-on-ubuntu-hardy-server/)

Comment: So to clarify, once you'll be in the cpan prompt, to install json_pp, you would need to run/type `JSON::PP` ; check the module's [page](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-PP-2.27103/bin/json_pp)